# wso2 micro-integrator 7.0.0 service chaining advanced

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to implement service chaining using **Integration-studio 7.0.0**

For.eg

Service 1(GET) - getCityById/{cityId}

**response**=> {"cityName":"Mumbai"}

Service 2(POST) -  getStateByCityName

(**it accepts above cityName inside body**)

**response**=> {"stateName":"Maharashtra"}

Service 3(GET) - getCountryByStateName/{stateName}

**response**=> {"countryName":"India"}

Service 1 returns me response as {"cityName":"Mumbai"}.

I set that response inside the payload and **call service 2**.
But service 2 doesn't get called.
Kindly let me know,how should i proceed further

Thanks for ur help in advance!

Below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/country1" name="CountryDetails" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="CITY"/>
            </call>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"cityName":"$1"}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.cityName"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="StateAPI"/>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors before calling service 2 ? Could you enable wire logs and https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/using-wire-logs/ and share the logs.

Comment: ERROR:
[2020-02-17 13:09:57,525]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - main sequence executed for call to non-existent = /country1

BELOW URL I'm CALLING:
curl -v http://localhost:8290/country1

@Nirothipan can you provide correct XML code for above scenario

Comment: From the error, it seems the endpoint is missing. Could you share your full synapse configs and logs.

Comment: @Nirothipan I'm able to proceed upto 2 levels (service 1 gets called,which returns reponse and i send that to service 2).
How do i set 2nd service response to 3rd service i.e I need to set "stateName"(which is returned by service 2) to service 3 (it accepts path as mentioned)
http://localhost:8081/getCountry/{uri.var.stateName}

Comment: Below metioned is the required code (which is working upto service 2):

<call>
 <endpoint key="STATE"/>
</call>
<call>
 <endpoint key="COUNTRY"/>
</call>
<respond/>